# Cron job is not working receiving email No input file specified

Tags: php, cron

I'm am in charge of a VPS with one hosted website.
I need to run a crop job for the site and am having much trouble with it.

From the cpanel for the site I'm running

```
php -q /home/siteusername/public_html/cron_764445573.php?nqL5yOfTqRoldguGujnJEN9hE44RTYT6cnFGd-F4uDI=-gVVUqf5mpesIwmFjY3cZDqly99nKP0PglHuyxzWKbI
```

However it is failing to work.
Please note that I had removed the sites user name for the purpose of posting code on the net.
I keep getting and email saying it has failed with the content 'No input file specified'.
I have most defiantly checked to make sure the path and file is correct. The file defiantly exist and does run correctly. The path is correct as taken form $_SERVER via php.

Is there something I'm missing?
I have done much research and from what I can tell it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you don't have a file name like that. What you probably have there is `/home/siteusername/public_html/cron_764445573.php`, right?

After that is where your troubles start. From the command line you can't append parameters like that (*file.php?foo=bar*) and expect it to be properly parsed.

What you need to do is to call the parameters like

```
php -q yourfile.php param1=value1 param2=value2
```

So in your case

```
php -q /home/siteusername/public_html/cron_764445573.php nqL5yOfTqRoldguGujnJEN9hE44RTYT6cnFGd-F4uDI=-gVVUqf5mpesIwmFjY3cZDqly99nKP0PglHuyxzWKbI
```

Comment: I tried that and it is still failing. I actually ran the job without any parameters and it still telling giving me the 'No input file specified' message. It there a way I can check/clarify this file location? From what I can decipher it is correct. This is the file root I use through all the coding in the website with no issues. Maybe it is incorrect.